# ggsignif package error stat_signif requires the following missing aesthetics: y

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, p-value

This is an invented example of my data:

```
x <- c("Control", "Case", "Case", "Case", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Case", "Case", "Case")
y <- c("Dead", "Dead", "Dead", "Alive", "Alive", "Dead", "Dead", "Dead", "Alive", "Dead")
```

I'm trying to represent this data in the form of a bar plot and then indicate a statistically significant difference in the proportion of alive and dead patients between the two experimental groups (cases and controls). I performed a Pearson's chi square test and the p-value is 4.674e-06.

This is my code for the plot:

```
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(data, aes(x = data$x,
             fill = data$y)) + 
geom_bar(aes(y = stat(count/sum(count))), position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
ylim(c(0, 0.4)) +
labs(x = NULL, y = "Proportion", fill = NULL) +
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Control", "Case")) +
geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Control", "Case"), map_signif_level = TRUE))
```

But then I get:

```
Error: stat_signif requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

Could anyone please tell me why this is happening and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to specify `y` in `ggplot()` and not only in `geom_bar()`? Besides use the bare column names in `aes()` and not `data$x` etc.

Comment: Hmm. Besides Markus’ comment, `geom_signif` doesn’t seem to work together with `geom_bar`.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the error message, `geom_signif` requires a `y` aesthetic, and you didn’t specify any.

Either move `y = stat(count/sum(count))` from `geom_bar` to your global aesthetics, or add it to `geom_signif`’s aesthetics.

Next, fix your aesthetics: instead of `data$x` and `data$y`, use `x` and `y`. Furthmore, you have an error in `geom_signif`: `map_signif_level = TRUE` needs to be *outside* the `comparisons`.

Finally, `geom_signif` doesn’t seem to be able to work with computed statistics in aesthetics. So you need to compute this statistic beforehand, e.g. via dplyr:

```
data %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    count(y) %>%
    mutate(Freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    aes(x, Freq, fill = y) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    geom_signif(
        comparisons = list(c("Control", "Case")),
        map_signif_level = TRUE
    )
```